# Can I reprogram $index in an ng-repeat if there's a sort involved?

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView = (phs.phrases | orderBy:phs.phrasesOrderBy[phs.phrasesOrderById].key:phs.phrasesSortDirectionId == 1)">
   <div>row.keyVal</div>
   <div>row.guid</div>
   <input ng-model="phs.phrases[$index].posId" />
   ...
   More display columns here
   ...
```

The problem is that sorting changes the $index so the posId that displays in between the divs is based on the $index AFTER sorting.

Is there some way I can have the ng-model set to the correct value when using a sort like this?

Note that every row has a guid.  Not sure if that helps but perhaps it could be of use.

Comment: Why don't you just order the phrases in your controller before passing them to your view? That's the way I'd go except you're allowing the user reorder the phrases...

Comment: I agree w/@regingprodigy.  $index is created for the sake of the loop therefore if you order this before you even get into the loop, index will be set to what you really, (the sorted position it sits in)

Comment: Because I am giving the user to reorder by different columns and either down or up dynamically without needing to retrieve more rows.

Comment: If that's the case, consider writing a custom order filter and keeping the sorted data in hand for further use.... Not sure if I'm being clear

Comment: use a hashmap object instead of array for `phs.phrases` and key it to row id

Comment: @charlietfl - If I used a hashmap could I still order it ? I'm not really sure how I would do that.

Comment: no, objects have no order.

Comment: Maybe its just me, but I'm having a hard time understanding what the desired behavior is. Would it be possible to elaborate with some test data?

Comment: Don't you just want to edit the posId of the current row? If so, just use `ng-model="row.posId"`

Answer (score 0):

> EDIT: updated answer after learning more about ng-repeat, changed my example data structure

**Can I reprogram $index in an ng-repeat if there's a sort involved?**

The short answer is NO.

**TLDR;** Based on what you have explained, `<input ng-model="row.posId" />` should be what you want. Also, think about re-organizing your data structure a little.

*Begin long-winded explanation:*

Because you can't reprogram it, relying on `$index` when using a filter on `ng-repeat` is usually a bad idea because it will not keep track of the order of the original list of items that is being filtered. In other words, you will run into unexpected behavior when doing something like:

```
   <input ng-model="phs.phrases[$index].posId" />

   Normal Result    Desired Filtered Result    Actual Filtered Result
   -------------    -----------------------    ----------------------
   A,1  $index=0     C,3 $index=2              C,3 $index=0
   B,2  $index=1     B,2 $index=1              B,2 $index=1
   C,3  $index=2     A,1 $index=0              A,1 $index=2
```

For anything that you would use $index for, you should use a unique identifier instead. However, in this particular case, you don't need to use the unique identifier. So, if your data structure is similar to:

```
$scope.phs={};
$scope.phs.phrasesOrderById ="1";
$scope.phs.phrasesSortDirectionId="1";
$scope.phs.phrases = [
    {"guid":"0", "keyVal":"A", "posId":"X"},
    {"guid":"1", "keyVal":"B", "posId":"Y"},
    {"guid":"2", "keyVal":"C", "posId":"Z"}
];
$scope.phs.phrasesOrderBy = [
    {"key":"1"},
    {"key":"2"},
    {"key":"3"}
];
```

I would suggest this as the immediate solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView = (phs.phrases | orderBy:phs.phrasesOrderBy[phs.phrasesOrderById].key:phs.phrasesSortDirectionId == 1)">
    <div>{{row.keyVal}}</div><!-- don't forget to interpolate with {{}} -->
    <div>{{row.guid}}</div><!-- don't forget to interpolate with {{}} -->
    <input ng-model="row.posId" />
   ...
</div
```

The reason I assumed that data structure is because you have references to two different arrays inside a `phs` object: `phs.phrases` and `phs.phrasesOrderBy`.

The way you currently have your data structure, `<input ng-model="row.posId" />` should work because you are `ng-repeat`ing on `phs.phrasesView` (which is just a filtered`phs.phrases`)  and getting `row`s from it.

**EXTRA**

You know your data better than me, but if there is no good reason to have three separate arrays, you could improve code readability if you combined the arrays into one like so:

```
$scope.phs={};
$scope.phs.phrasesOrderById ="1";
$scope.phs.phrasesSortDirection="1";
$scope.phs.phrases = [
    {"guid":"0", "keyVal":"A", "posId":"X", "key":"1"},
    {"guid":"1", "keyVal":"B", "posId":"Y", "key":"2"},
    {"guid":"2", "keyVal":"C", "posId":"Z", "key":"3"}
];
```

If you keep using the two arrays that you have, I'd expect you to run into problems if they get out of sync (aren't filtered the same way).Having only one array makes it easier to understand your code, and also prevents the extra effort to keep the two arrays in sync. Your code would then look like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in phs.phrases = (phs.phrases | orderBy:phs.phrases[phs.phrasesOrderById].key:phs.phrasesSortDirectionId == 1)">
    <div>row.keyVal</div><!-- don't forget to interpolate with {{}} -->
    <div>row.guid</div><!-- don't forget to interpolate with {{}} -->
    <input ng-model="row.posId" />
    ...
</div
```